# Why temperature co efficient value differ in different approach in calculation?

Tags: electrical-resistance

Q. resistance value is 18 ohm at 20 degree and 20 ohm at 50 degree. Find temp co efficient.

sol 1-
R=Rref(1+a(T-Tref))  a=temp co efficient

=>20=18(1+a(50-20))  => a=1/270

sol2 -
let Ro is resistance at 0 degree R=Ro(1+a(T-0)) =>R=Ro(1+aT)

=>18=Ro(1+a(20-0))

=>20=Ro(1+a(50-0))

dividing =>18/20=(1+20a)/(1+50a) =>it gives a=1/250

i am very confused right now cant figure out where i am doing mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On what basis are you dividing the two equations

Comment: i have two equation and two variables. to cancel out R0 i am dividing equation 1 by 2

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is treating $a$ and $R_o$ as independent variables in the two equations, which they are not. There is only one independent variable on the right side of each equation, $T$.

Both equations are for supposed to be for resistors of the same material. $a$ is only a function of the resistivity of that material. That means $a$ has to be the same for both equations. The value of $R_o$ should also be the same for both equations since it has only one unique value at 0$^0$C for a given $a$.

If you solve each equation for $R_o$ for the same value of $a$ You will get  different values of $R_o$. Just like you can’t have different values of $a$ for the same material, you can’t have two different values of the reference resistance for the same reference temperature.

Hope this helps.